# Home Directories and pam.d using LDAP

Tags: users, pam, home, ldap

Background:
I'm not too familiar with the ins and outs of pam and LDAP authentication on a configuration side. I've used systems that use pam but I've only worked on applications, not systems themselves.

Questions:
Using pam to control authentication via LDAP, does this mean that a home directory will not be created on the system?

If not, would I create users on the server or somehow push users to the system from an LDAP source?

Comment: This question might be related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106391/34796

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is exactly what `pam_mkhomedir` was made for.
The `pam_mkhomedir` module can create the user's home directory upon login if that directory does not exist.

How to install it depends upon your distribution. But you would need to put it in one or more files in `/etc/pam.d`.
For example, on my system I have `/etc/pam.d/system-login` which is included by all other services which perform login (ssh, gdm, etc).
I would put `pam_mkhomedir.so` in the `session` stack, such as:

```
session     optional    pam_loginuid.so
session     required    pam_env.so 
session     optional    pam_lastlog.so 
session     include     system-auth
session     optional    pam_mkhomedir.so # <<< right here
session     optional    pam_ck_connector.so nox11
session     optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session     optional    pam_motd.so motd=/etc/motd
```

Where you put it is entirely dependent upon what else is in the stack. But you should put it before anything else which might need the home directory.

See `man 8 pam_mkhomedir` for the options it supports.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the answer. Our users currently don't log into the system, they log into a web application that is hosted on the system. Is there a trigger that can create their home directory upon an initial log in of the web app?

Comment: If the web application uses the pam stack, then it would work (though you might have to put it in the `auth` stack instead of `session`). If the app does not use the pam stack, then you would have to build something into the application itself.

Comment: It looks like only the session module is provided, I have tried and, in fact, pam_mkhomedir is not working with the auth module. I have the same problem as Nicholas Anderson, I have a web application. Is there any way to solve this issue in the auth module?

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 14.04 `system-login` is not present, but another file named as `common-session` is present.

I went there and put:

```
root@GW:~# vim /etc/pam.d/common-session

#
session optional        pam_systemd.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0077
```

This will create home directory if no exist also set the permission to `700`

Comment: The umask suggested by https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication  is  `umask=0022`.  I believe yours removes ALL capabilities including `read` which may prevent some key based authentication/trust mechanisms from working in a multi-user system or other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using **oddjob-mkhomedir**:

For Centos 7 this works:

```
yum install oddjob-mkhomedir
```

Append this to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`:

```
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel
```

And finally:

```
systemctl enable oddjob; systemctl start oddjob
```

This was posted originally here: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=48631

Note: If you just mounted your `/home` partition, don't forget to do `restorecon /home`

Comment: Thanks! Your `restorecon /home` note has just saved me after many hours of futile searching

Comment: I'm running rasbian buster and there is no `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` or `/etc/pam.d/password-auth`. Could you possibly suggest where I might put the configuration line?